# How to customize response using Grape API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, httpresponse, ruby-grape

I am working in Grape API for a project and I  have the below scenario. I have 2 tables from where I need to fetch the response. Initial requirement was, I have an entity called "job" where I have to show id and name. So I have exposed the id and name as below.

module XYZPublicApi

module V1

class Job < Grape::Entity

with_options(expose_nil: true) do

expose :id,

expose :name

end

But, after changed requirement,
In response I have to show id and name of job and another field from another object "config" - configDetails (string type)

So the response will be as example

id: id123

name : job124

configDetails: configdetails123

What I have done in this changed requirement, I have made another class in entities/v1

class Config < Grape::Entity

with_options(expose_nil: true) do

expose :configDetails

end

and modified the class Job as below-

class Job < Grape::Entity

with_options(expose_nil: true) do

expose :id,

expose :name

expose :configDetails using XYZPublicAPI::V1::Config

end

But in response I am seeing -

id: id123

name : job124

configDetails: null

Could someone please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: What if you create a method which will return config_details and merge here. something like below
**expose :configDetails, merge: true**

`def configDetails
     {configDetails: get_required_data}
  end`